# Better/Nicest way to symlink into multiple folders?

Tags: bash, symlink

I have this directory structure, and I need to generate symlinks for `common/provider.tf` in both `environments/prod` and `environments/prod/module`.

```
/
├─ common
│  ├─ provider.tf
├─ environments/
│  ├─ prod/
│  │  ├─ module/
```

I managed to do it this way:

```
  if [ -e "../../../common/provider.tf" ]; then  # I'm in environments/prod/module
    ln -s ../../../common/provider.tf provider.tf
  else  # I'm in the root folder "/"
    ln -s common/provider.tf $environment/provider.tf  # $environment is /environments/prod
  fi
```

But I realize that my code sucks and I can't come up with a better idea.

Any idea on how to do it better?
Note: There are lots of environments and lots of modules, I'm using that code recursively.

Comment: Is there a reason why you at this stage of the script don't know which your current directory is?

Comment: @TedLyngmo this script is called from a legacy script that I can't modify, and it's called from two locations (both root folder and /environments/(module)/(folder) )

Comment: Ok, then can't you save the current directory, `OWD="$PWD"` and `cd /`,  then `ln -s common/provider.tf "$environment"` and finally `cd "$OWD"`?

Answer (score 1):

Store the absolute path to the root directory, and construct the various link destination paths relative to this reference root directory.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

root_dir='/absolute/path/to/root/dir'
provider_tf="${root_dir}/common/provider.tf"
prod_dir="${root_dir}/environments/prod"
module_dir="${prod_dir}/module"

for dest_dir in "${prod_dir}" "${module_dir}"; do
  ln --symbolic --relative "${provider_tf}" "${dest_dir}/"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The OS actually doesn't care at all what your symlink points to. You can do

```
ln -s /no/such/path brokenlink
```

and similarly you can

```
ln -s ../../../common/provider.tf environments/prod/module/provider.tf
```

regardless of what your current directory is; the symlink will be resolved relative to the directory where you created it.

Unfortunately, `ln` only allows you to create a single symlink at a time; but with this, you could also create the links from the project's base directory with a simple loop.

```
for dest in environment environment/prod
do
    ln -s $PWD/common/provider.tf "$dest"
done
```

The variable `$PWD` is a Bash built-in (but not available in `sh`, which you had also originally tagged your question as; perhaps see also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)) - you could also add a `--relative` option to convert it to a relative symlink like Léa proposes if you have GNU `ln` (but again, this is not properly portable to [POSIX `ln`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html)). (If you need POSIX/`sh` portability, you can add `PWD=$(pwd)` before the loop.)